# How do i perform operations on matrix rows while keeping the matrix intact?

Tags: matlab

Question/problem summary:

Create a 10 by 10 matrix whose first column is the numbers **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10**
the next column contains the squares of first column: **1, 4, 9,...,100**
the third column contains the 3rd power of first column: **1, 8, 27,..., 1000**.
the 10th column contains the 10th power of the first column.

Background:

This is for a class assignment, intro to analytical programming. I have tried the following code, but i am not sure why it is not giving the correct output. Any advice or suggestions is appreciated.

```
    row1 = [1:10]
    tenXtenMatrix = repmat(row1,10,1)
    [row col] = size(tenXtenMatrix)
    for i=2:row
        for j=1:col
            tenXtenMatrix(i,:).^i
        end
    end
```

what is expected:

```
     1     2     3     4     5     6         7        8           9          10

     1     4     9    16    25    36        49       64          81         100

     1     8    27    64    125   216      343      512         729        1000

     1    16    81    256   625   1296    2401     4096        6561       10000
     etc..
```

what i got:

```
    0.0000  0.0000   0.0000  0.0001   0.0010 0.0060  0.0282 0.1074  0.3487  1.0000
    0.0000  0.0000   0.0000  0.0001   0.0010 0.0060  0.0282 0.1074  0.3487  1.0000
    0.0000  0.0000   0.0000  0.0001   0.0010 0.0060  0.0282 0.1074  0.3487  1.0000
    0.0000  0.0000   0.0000  0.0001   0.0010 0.0060  0.0282 0.1074  0.3487  1.0000
    etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
x = 1:10  
A = x.^(x.')
```

Where:

- [.^](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) is the [element-wise power](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) operator
- [.'](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) is the [transpose](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) operator

More informations about implicit expansion [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html).

Answer (score 0):

Fixes:

1. you run on j and not using it.
2. you calculate the power but not updating the matrix

```
    row1 = [1:10];
    tenXtenMatrix = repmat(row1,10,1);
    [row col] = size(tenXtenMatrix);
    for i=2:row
      tenXtenMatrix(i,:) = tenXtenMatrix(i,:).^i;
    end
```